# Не подключается footer в Bitrix 1c

Tags: битрикс

При подключении сайта header появляется, а внизу где footer вылезает ошибка
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/u4720550/data/www/aobuh.ru/cnindex_include.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/u4720550/data/www/aobuh.ru/cn/index.php on line 5

Я уже смотрела подобные вопросы, но ответ так и не нашла

Comment: Требуемый файл так и должен называться — `cnindex_include.php` — или слэш забыли поставить?